# like OR operator in Cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am new to cakephp and I want to add *or*, *and*, and *like* to my existing query.

I want to make a condition like this

```
WHERE  'Message.user_id = Contact.user_id' AND 'Message.mobileNo LIKE'=>"%Contact.mobileNo" OR LIKE'=>"%Contact.homeNo" OR LIKE'=>"%Contact.workNo"
```

My query is

```
$this->bindModel(array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'Contact' => array(
                'className' => 'Contact',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Message.user_id = Contact.user_id',
                    'Message.mobileNo = Contact.mobileNo'
                ),
                'type' => 'inner'
            )
        )
    ), false); 

      $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array(),
        'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')));
```

Comment: The query in the question does not look to make any sense - why do you want to check for phone numbers ending in the text "Contact.xxxNo" (which _is_ what you've asked for)?

Comment: @AD7six yup i know ... acutually it was just for here.. my purpose was to just use oR and like operator

Comment: that's a bad habit :P - real questions get real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like below in your existing query.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            array(
                "Message.mobileNo LIKE" => "%Contact.mobileNo",
            ),
            array(
                "Message.mobileNo LIKE" => "%Contact.homeNo",
            ),
            array(
                "Message.mobileNo LIKE" => "%Contact.workNo",
            )
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')
));
```

And you can also refer [Detail Document for simple search with like](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/saravana/2011/01/14/simple_search_in_cakephp_using_find_conditions)

Comment: i paste your query as it is but is giving me  syntax errors .. i think u are missing something a comma or a bracket

Comment: i am actualy working on a eclipse ... so it is showing me a red line under the "OR" it means some thing is not right.. if you want me to check this in browser then i can do it as well ..but i surely it will give me an error there too

Answer (score 0):

you can use: for "like"

> $this->Post->find("all",array('condition'=>array('Author
>   LIKE'=>"ad%")));

above query will give You the data from table posts where author name starts with "ad".

for "OR"

> $this->Post->find("all",array('condition'=>array("OR"=>array('Author
>   LIKE'=>"ad%",'Author LIKE'=>"bo%"))));

above query will give You the data from table posts where author name starts with "ad" OR "bo"

This [blog](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/08/cakephp-model-find-conditions/) post can b useful to u as well!